# Open "Mail App Extension" preferences panel with Swift in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, mailkit

Mail App Extensions were announced by Apple at WWDC21. The implementation is very similar to Safari App Extensions. With the method `showPreferencesForExtension(withIdentifier:completionHandler:)` of the `SFSafariApplication` class it is possible to launch Safari and open the preferences panel for a specific Safari app extension.

Example Code:

```
import SafariServices

SFSafariApplication.showPreferencesForExtension(withIdentifier: "example") { error in
    // error handling...
}
```

In addition, the state of the extension can be checked. This is useful to show the user in the container app if the extension is enabled. You can implement this using the `getStateOfSafariExtension(withIdentifier:completionHandler:)` method of the `SFSafariExtensionManager` class.

Example Code:

```
import SafariServices

SFSafariExtensionManager.getStateOfSafariExtension(withIdentifier: "example") { state, error in
    // check state and error handling...
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found any ways to implement this for Mail App Extensions yet. Of course, I know that I can open the Mail App quite easily with `NSWorkspace`:

```
if let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mail") {
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}
```

...but this is just a workaround and not a solution. I want to open the "Mail App Extension" preferences panel and read the status of the extension. Am I missing an API for this?

[image]